# Dual of essentially compactly supported functions on a hemi-compact Radon space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, limits-and-colimits, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a [hemicompact](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hemicompact+space) [Radon space](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Radon_measure) and fix a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$.  Let $L(X_n)$ denote the subspace of $L_{\mu}^1(X)$ of "functions" which are $\mu$-essentially supported on $X$.  Let $L_c(X)$ denote the colimit (LB-space) of the direct system $\{L(X_n)\hookrightarrow L(X_m):\, n\leq m\}$ in the category of locally-convex spaces and continuous linear maps.

**My question is**:  *Is there a concrete interpretation, possibly in terms of measures on $X$, of the continuous dual $L_c(X)'$?*

---

**For comparison:**
I know that the continuous dual of $C_c(X)'$ (with its $LB$-topology; constructed in the analogous manner) [can be identified with the set of Radon measures on $X$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220511/questions-on-topologies-on-space-of-radon-measures).  Is there an analogous interpretation of $L_c(X)$?

Comment: Do you really mean the *category of locally convex spaces and continuous maps* or rather the continuous and linear maps? Moreover, $X_n$ is probably a *compact exhaustion* of $X$, right?

Comment: Roughly, the dual of the LB-space is the projective limit of the duals. My guess is thus, that $L_c(X)'$ is the space of measurable function whose restrictions to all $X_n$ are $\mu$-a.e. bounded.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth  I was especially wondering if it had an interpretation as some sort of (Radon?) measures... do you think so?  Also yes to your first point.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, the dual of $L^1(X,\mu)$ is $L^\infty(X,\mu)$. In the hemi-compact case, the dual is the projective limit of $L^\infty(X_n,\mu)$. What else do you want? Somewhat artificially, you can identify $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ with a space of measures, assigning to each bounded function $f$ the measure with $\mu$-density $f$.